# include navigation and wrapper in all pages and insert new content in each page

Tags: php, html, navigation, include, wrapper

I have a navigation bar and wrapper saved in `header.php` and have included it on my `content.php` page. but when i load the `content.php` page, the content from `content.php` is outside the wrapper from the `header.php` page.

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="navigation">
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<h1>Welcome to my home page.</h1>
<p>Some text.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you define your wrapper for your navigation menu (which is in your header.php file). If you want your wrapper to wrap your whole document define this in your content.php file.